# Spring Boot Database initialization failed: SimpleDriverDataSource could not initialize class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to run tests with Spring Boot context but I am getting an error "**Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource**".

I am struggling with this problem for a few days now and can not get it working. Probably I am not familiar enough with Spring Boot testing, but on Spring Boot version 2.3.4 everything worked fine. After upgrading to 2.5.7 and later, (2.6.1) problem persists.

Test class:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
        "spring.sql.init.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE",
        "spring.sql.init.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver",
        "spring.sql.init.username=user",
        "spring.sql.init.password=pass",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update",
        "spring.jpa.show-sql=true"
}
)
public class UserServiceTest {

    private static final String USERNAME_COLUMN = "username";

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    @AfterEach
    public void cleanDatabase() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        roleRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldRegisterUser() {
        roleRepository.saveAndFlush(RoleFixture.createRoleEntity(UserType.USER.name()));

        final String username = "username";
        final UserType type = UserType.USER;

        final UserRegister userRegister = UserFixture.createUserRegister(
                username,
                "password",
                "email@test.com",
                25,
                "name",
                "last_name",
                type
        );
        final UserResponse userResponse = userService.registerUser(userRegister);

        assertThat(userResponse).isNotNull();
        assertThat(userResponse.getUserId()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(userResponse.getUsername()).isEqualTo(username);
        assertThat(userResponse.getType()).isEqualTo(type);

        assertThat(userRepository.findByUserId(userResponse.getUserId())).isNotEmpty();
    }
```

Context intializer class:

```
package hr.fitbit.demo.fitbitconnect.testsupport;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "hr.fitbit.demo.fitbitconnect")
public class TestApplication {
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
 <!-- spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried to include spring-boot-data-jpa, h2, spring-boot-jdbc dependencies but nothing helped. Here is the link to the project https://github.com/filip194/fitbit-connect and link to the test: https://github.com/filip194/fitbit-connect/blob/master/subprojects/users/src/test/java/hr/fitbit/demo/fitbitconnect/users/service/UserServiceTest.java.

I have also tried to remove **@AutoConfigureTestDatabase** but then I got another error:
**Could not initialize class com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource**, which I also could not find solution for, even though I explicitly included dependency in the pom.

I am currently stuck with this and can not move further with my educational project. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** using **spring.datasource.** or **spring.sql.init.** properties does not change test results or error messages in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you the following decision:

1. Add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan`

```
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {UserRepository.class,  RoleRepository.class})
   //@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "hr.fitbit.demo.fitbitconnect.dao.repository")
   @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {UserEntity.class, RoleEntity.class})
   @SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
   public class UserServiceTest {
```

2. In module `dao` add class with `@SpringBootApplication` to folder `dao/src/test/java`

```
   package hr.fitbit.demo.fitbitconnect.dao;

   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class MockTestApplication {
   }
```

and

```
    @DataJpaTest
    public class RoleEntityTest {
```

more info here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-unable-to-find-springbootconfiguration-with-datajpatest

3. Add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` to TestSupport class and FitbitServiceTest class.

Good luck!